# Parametrize a surface involving the intersection of a cylinder and a plane.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

In the question below, I am trying to understand how $S$ is a the graph of a function of two variables so that it can be parametrized $f(x,y) = (x,y,z(x,y))$. Note on the picture below, formula 1 is the dot product of a vector field with a parametrized surface, parametrized as in $f$ above.

[image]

Comment: The intersection of the two sets as written will be a curve, not a surface. Do you mean for the cylinder to be defined as $x^2+y^2\leq 1$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The points in the solid cylinder can be written as $(r\cos(\theta), r\sin(\theta), z)$ for $r\in [0, 1]$, $\theta\in \mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{Z}$, and $z\in \mathbb{R}$. The points in the plane are exactly the points $(x, y, z)$ that satisfy $z = 1-x-y$. Therefore, the surface of intersection can be parametrized as $$S : [0, 1]\times \mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{R}^3, (r, \theta)\mapsto (r\cos(\theta), r\sin(\theta), 1-r(\cos(\theta)+\sin(\theta)))$$

Comment: I am not looking for the intersection curve, but rather a function expressing the entire surface below the plane.

Comment: All that is is the points $(r\cos(\theta), r\sin(\theta), z)$ for $r\in [0, 1]$, $\theta\in \mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{Z}$, and $0\leq z\leq 1-r(\cos(\theta)+\sin(\theta))$. I've modified the answer to include a set definition of the points in the cylinder and below the plane, but there is no single algebraic equation whose solution is the points in the set, because the points in the set are not an algebraic variety.

Comment: Also, it looks like you've just changed the problem from an infinite cylinder to a cylinder of height $1$. Generally speaking, if you intend to ask a different question, you should ask a different question rather than editing an existing one.

Comment: The context that I saw this problem is in an example using Stokes theorem for graphs, implying the surface can be represented as a graph. And sorry about the edit.

Comment: Are you sure that the problem isn't to integrate around $C$ versus integrate over the two-dimensional surface bounded by $C$, then? That surface can be written as $z = 1-r(\cos(\theta)+\sin(\theta))$ for $(r, \theta)\in [0, 1]\times \mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{Z}$, as I stated above.

Comment: The author does it both ways, I can post the snippet if you wish.

Comment: I think that would clarify the problem a bit. For example, there's no indication from the diagram that the cylinder is not infinite, as it clearly includes points that lie below $z = 0$ (otherwise, the curve of intersection is not an ellipse as pictured). Furthermore, we don't usually refer to a three-dimensional subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ as a "surface."

Comment: That's what I thought. Looking at the book solution, it's apparent that what the author intends is not for you to integrate over the region "below" the intersection of the solid cylinder and the plane, but over the surface of intersection itself. This surface can be parametrized as I stated originally, i.e. $$S : [0, 1]\times \mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{R}^3, (r, \theta)\mapsto (r\cos(\theta), r\sin(\theta), 1-r(\cos(\theta)+\sin(\theta)))$$

Comment: Ok, hopefully this clears things up.

Comment: ok, my mistake! thanks so much, I will award the bounty.

Comment: Thanks! Glad to have cleared up your questions about the problem.

Comment: @MichaelLee  What does the notation $\mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{Z}$ mean. Does it mean $ \mathbb R $ modulo $ 2 \pi $?

Comment: @MichaelLee And why not just use the domain $ [0, 2\pi] $ instead of $ \mathbb R / 2 \pi \mathbb Z ?$

Comment: Yes, $\mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{Z}$ is the reals modulo $2\pi$. You could use $[0, 2\pi)$ if you want, but I generally prefer the notation I used for a couple of reasons.